# What is the best way of programatically getting advert data? (link and cpm)

Tags: facebook, ads

As I understand it the ads API should give me the information I want but AFAIK it's restricted to ad companies only even, although I only want to query my current settings, not place ads using it.

The automated e-mail seemed like a good idea, but it just sends you a link so I would still need to be logged on.

Even when logged on, using the web reports I can't get the link, using the power editor I can't get the CPM.

I could download both of them and combine the results, but surely there must be an easier way (also the csvs from the web and power editor are different, one is comma separated UTF-8, the other is tab separated UCS-2).